# Delta in Chernoff bounds for Sequence of Poisson Trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The upper Chernoff bound for a sequence of independent Poisson trials with $P(X_i ) = p_i$, $X = ∑X_i$, and $µ = E[X]$ is said to be represented by:
$$
Pr(X \ge (1+\delta)\mu) \le \left(\frac{e^\delta}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}\right)^\mu
$$
What is $\delta$ representing here?

Comment: How much $X $ exceeds the mean, in units of the mean. It is on the left side...

Comment: of course, it's terribly obvious now - thank you for pointing that out.